# higher order functions using arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

I am trying to create a higher order function in javascript `someMathArray(x) { }` that returns a function and takes another single argument. I want the function to take an original array, say `[1,2,3,4]` then apply another function for example, named `mult2(a) { return a*2 }`(however, I want this to work for any function I pass in. I don't want mult2(a) to be hard coded into the function) and then return an array containing `[2,4,6,8]`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
function someMathArray(array) {
  return function(fun) {
    return array.map(fun);
  };
}

var fun = someMathArray([1,2,3,4,5]);
var output = fun(function(a) { return a*2; });
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

or

```js
function someMathArray(array) {
  return array.map.bind(array);
}

var fun = someMathArray([1,2,3,4,5]);
var output = fun(function(a) { return a*2; });
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was having trouble wrapping my head around how higher order functions work, but your answer helped me understand what they are really doing.

Comment: How would I handle the case that the array is empty?

Comment: @ilikecake1 `[].map(function(a) { return a*2; })` will return empty array.